# How to find if parent of USB device is a hub

Tags: c++, winapi, usb

I need to find out if parent of USB device is a hub or host.
Current plan is to use CM_Get_Parent() to get the DEVINST and use SetupDiGetDeviceInfoListDetail() to get the SP_DEVINFO_LIST_DETAIL_DATA structure, but from there I am looking for information to parse against to will tell me if the parent is a hub.

Any pointers/hints/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

EB

Comment: This is definitely a programming question, about the win32 setup API.  And note to tag editors: it has nothing to do with `networking`.

Answer (score 4):

Parent is always a hub.  Might be a root hub or a peripheral hub, I guess that's what you want to know.  Check the grandparent's enumerator property (whether it's on a `USB` or `PCI` bus).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am finding that I need to make similar calls to what what is done in the USBView sample application from the WDK. So naturally I am running into linking issues as I need to do this from a user mode library/application... error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HOST_CONTROLLER  and adding the libraries used by USBView does not resolve the link error.

Comment: That looks to me like a header file problem, not a library link problem.  This may be relevant: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130869

Comment: "Parent is always a hub" - Parent is USB device (`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE` interface class) in my case...

Comment: @D.Stark: A USB device can have child devices of its own (for example, a USB SD card reader could have the SD card as a child device), but the child device is not itself a USB device, unless the parent is a hub.

Comment: I enumerate `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK` devices.

Comment: I use Setup API and it's strange that some properties (which `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` retrieves) do not exist for a `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK`, but exist for `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE`. For example, `SPDRP_LOCATION_INFORMATION`. This is apparently the same USB device.

Comment: @D.Stark: Correct, a mass storage USB device will likely be the parent of a disk device (which in turn will be a parent of one or more volumes).  This is expected.  Since the disk is indirectly a descendant of the USB bus, not directly attached (there's the mass storage controller in between) it will not have USB bus-related properties like Location Information.

Comment: And how to determine that the `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK` device is a SSD, HDD or USB Flash Storage device? Retrieve `STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR` structure and check `DeviceType` field (0 - direct-access block device)?

Comment: USB hubs in system can be several and the host controller is always one?

Comment: @D.Stark: Most tools apparently check the rotational speed in the SMART data -- SSDs have 0 rotation, hard disks have eg 5400 rpm or 7200 rpm

Comment: @D.Stark: There is one root hub per host controller root complex.  Most chipsets embed multiple host controllers, and there's always the possibility of add-in cards which would be independent host controllers as well.  Take a look at your Device Manager in "Show devices by connection" mode sometime.

Comment: "Most tools apparently check the rotational speed in the SMART data" - I mean to determine whether the device is one of the above - not to distinguish one from the other. In order to distinguish USB disk from internal HDD or SSD, needs to know the type of bus (`STORAGE_BUS_TYPE`). True?

Comment: I would tend to just walk the chain of parent devices until you reach one with an "Enumerator" property that you recognize.  Likely values include "USBSTOR", "USB" (generally on the parent device of the "USBSTOR" disk), "SCSI" (which also appears on SATA drives), "PCI" (on SATA host controllers and probably also on NVMe SSD disks)

Comment: Okey. But what does this property mean and are these all possible values?

Comment: Why is it not enough to check if the device is direct-access block device?

Comment: @D.Stark: `STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR` requires sending `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`, that needs a handle to the device.  Also, some devices won't support it, some will be locked, some will require admin rights.  Much less hassle to simply look at SetupDi properties.  Also, I was answering "In order to distinguish USB disk from internal HDD or SSD" part of your comment

Comment: Still interesting topic with MBR. If we talk about MBR, is it worth it to independently parse structure or can I rely on the `DISK_GEOMETRY_EX`? There are 5 (AAP with PTS-DOS 6.60 and DR-DOS 7.07), 7 (AST and NEC MS-DOS 3.x as well as Storage Dimensions SpeedStor) or even 17 entries (Ontrack Disk Manager) in MBR by convension.

Comment: @D.Stark: That has absolutely nothing to do with this question.  At least your earlier comments had something to do with checking whether things were connected to a USB hub.

Comment: "Also, some devices won't support it, some will be locked, some will require admin rights." - I need to get a device handle to retrieve the serial number and bus type. Or the serial can be obtained in another way?

Comment: "That has absolutely nothing to do with this question. At least your earlier comments had something to do with checking whether things were connected to a USB hub." - I will create a separate question.

Comment: "I would tend to just walk the chain of parent devices until you reach one with an "Enumerator" property that you recognize." - `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` requires `SP_DEVINFO_DATA` which retrives `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo`. And `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` requires `DeviceNumber` as `MemberIndex`. How to get `DeviceNumber` without `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER`?

Comment: @D. Stark: Use `CM_Get_DevNode_Property` when walking the chain of parent devices, since that needs `CM_Get_Parent` anyway.  (To get started, read the `DevInst` property of `SP_DEVINFO_DATA`)

Comment: Well. What's with the serial number and bus type?

Comment: @D.Stark: For those you may well need to send IOCTLs.  We're again getting very far off of the topic of "is it connected through a USB hub?".

Comment: "Use CM_Get_DevNode_Property when walking the chain of parent devices, since that needs CM_Get_Parent anyway" - `CM_Get_DevNode_Property` is part of the Unified Device Property Model => Available in Microsoft Windows Vista and later versions of Windows. No variants for Windows XP?

Comment: @D.Stark: `CM_Get_DevNode_Registry_PropertyW` is available since Win2k, just like `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty`  But be warned that handling of a bunch of properties is different in Win2k and WinXP vs newer versions, e.g. Location and Bus-Provided Device Description return different values from the same hardware and same vendor driver.

Comment: But is suitable for enumerator name?

Comment: Yes, the "Enumerator" is available pre-Vista.  Pass `CM_DRP_ENUMERATOR_NAME` to `CM_Get_DevNode_Registry_PropertyW`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60737102/smart-rcv-drive-data-deviceiocontrol-error-access-denied

Comment: "Most tools apparently check the rotational speed in the SMART data - SSDs have 0 rotation, hard disks have eg 5400 rpm or 7200 rpm" - I cant find anything like this in the [attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.).

Comment: @D.Stark: Actually it appears in the result of the ATA "IDENTIFY DEVICE" command, word 217 "Nominal media rotation rate"

Comment: Great! Also I need to get HDD bus type, but STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR.BusType field does not contain the correct information. For example, type of my HDD bus is NVMe, but field says that it is RAID. Are there other ways to get this information? HWiNFO gives not only the type of bus but also the supported protocol version. I've been looking for an answer to this question for a long time.

Comment: @D.Stark: Run CrystalDiskInfo and choose "Copy Info" from the menu, it breaks the information down by source (ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE, SMART, etc).  Note that NVMe is not actually a "bus type", it's a programming model for the disk controller.  The bus is PCIe.

Comment: @D.Stark: This may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/working-with-nvme-devices

Comment: @D.Stark: Also note that it's possible that the drive is behind a RAID layer.  In that case BusType would be RAID, but you'd still be able to query the underlying physical connection via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-storage_physical_device_data

Comment: Therefore, the field contains the correct data? But how to get a programming model for the disk controller and it's version (for example, NVMe v1.2)?

Comment: And why then `STORAGE_BUS_TYPE` enumeration contains `BusTypeNvme` member if it isn't bus type but programming model?..

Comment: _"I would tend to just walk the chain of parent devices until you reach one with an "Enumerator" property that you recognize. Likely values include "USBSTOR", "USB" (generally on the parent device of the "USBSTOR" disk), "SCSI" (which also appears on SATA drives), "PCI" (on SATA host controllers and probably also on NVMe SSD disks)"_ - Can't there be IDE?)

Comment: @D.Stark: Drivers for most PATA and SATA host controllers were implemented as "SCSI miniport" drivers because that was a much more powerful driver interface.  So device manager sees PCI (or PCIe) bus between CPU and host controller, and SCSI bus between host controller and drive, even if it's a virtual SCSI bus abstracting a real PATA or SATA connection.

Comment: @benvoigt I tried start code on another disk and it returned IDE enumerator type. Is the type of enumerator type worth looking at all? I just list all devices that have `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK` interface class. Isn't all such devices have MBR? As far as I know, it must be random-access block devices.

Comment: No, not all block storage devices have MBR-style partition table.  I don't know what you mean by "I tried start code".  If the enumerator came back as "IDE" great, you have more information.  But just because you did get "IDE" from one IDE disk doesn't mean you will get that from every IDE disk.  Many will return "SCSI" or "RAID"

Comment: _"I don't know what you mean by "I tried start code""_ - *I tried to start code. _"Many will return "SCSI" or "RAID""_ - This is not the question. The question is to find all USB Flash, HDD and SSD devices on computer. I thought it was not enough for the device to have `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK` interface class, so I asked about the types of the enumerator. Speaking generally: I need to find all devices that have MBR and then work with it.

Comment: @benvoigt Why [this](https://uxd.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004396211-S-M-A-R-T-Attributes-Table-supported-by-Samsung-NVMe-Drives-) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) SMART attributes doesn't match? `DeviceIoControl` returns attributes as in wiki article and CrystalDiskInfo shows another attributes...

Comment: @benvoigt And yet it’s strange that the concepts of physical bus and protocol are mixed in the STORAGE_BUS_TYPE enumeration. Or am I confusing something?

Comment: Probably when the API was designed, there were no standardized protocols at all, every driver completely reimplemented the programmatic interface to its own host controller.  And then when standards were added, they were added along with new busses when the bus specification writer said "we have to have a standard for this".  So the API of "bus type" continued to work.  Now when we discover the original standard isn't good enough (e.g. USB Mass Storage class has terrible performance) and make a new protocol (e.g. UASP), the API naming is already baked into a million codebases.

Comment: @benvoigt Strictly speaking, NVMe and UASP are access protocols, and (P)ATA, SATA, IEEE1394, SCSI and USB are bus types. True?