# How to find USB Host Controller by plugged USB device

Tags: c, winapi, usb

I need to find USB Host Controller by plugged USB device. I need it to set a specific registry key for that controller which is required to fix [KB928631](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928631).
I am able to get device handle and get the parent device handle using `CM_Get_Parent()` function.

Unfortunately, there is no information about number of HUBs, so I don’t know how many times `CM_Get_Parent()` should be called to reach the Host Controller.

Is there any Controller specific data which could be used to differentiate it from HUB?

Currently I am getting `CM_DRP_LOCATION_INFORMATION` property to and determine whether the string returned by the property started by "PCI bus". If so assume that current device is Host Controller.
Is this a reliable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834951/how-to-find-if-parent-of-usb-device-is-a-hub/3835894#3835894), I mention that the "Enumerator" property is better for this than "Location".

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But how can be explaiend that the "Enumerator" property is more reliable that the "Location"?

Comment: @gtikok: Because I've observed the Location property to vary quite a bit based on Windows version, where the Enumerator property seems to be more consistent.  And you don't have bus numbers mixed in with "Enumerator", you can compare the entire string instead of a prefix match.